# Open only one record JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, singleton

I'm developing a small desktop application for my college java project.

There's a main window which contains a `JTable` and when i click a specific record it pops out another `JFrame` containing full details of specific record.

When I click a record and if I click another record without manually closing the first one it still exists.. (anyway it's obvious).

I want to get the first frame to be disposed when ever I click another.

Simply I want only one frame containing details at a time, with the main window..

- I tried it couple of time using `JPanel` objects instead of frames and it was useless.
- And tried this with singleton pattern and when I use it only one frame pops out at a time still.. Contains the same details for every record I click in the table..

What is a method to get this requirement done?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  There should be exactly **1 frame per application instance.**  The 'Details' view should appear in a `JDialog`.  The app. should keep a reference to the dialog and change the state of it (i.e. change the details) when the user chooses a new record to display.

Comment: *"I tried it couple of time using JPanel objects instead of frames and it was useless."*  DYM by using a `CardLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new jFrame everytime user clicks on table record, create one jframe first time & reuse the same jframe everytime, it will be good if you can reuse the components of the jframe. 
You can use [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) in place of jframe.
Post some code as it will be helpful in providing a better solution.

Comment: You can't use a JInternalFrame as a popup. A JInternalFrame is designed to be displayed in a JDesktopPane. Use a modal JDialog as the popup window.